# FastAPI and multipart/related - status 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: python, fastapi, multipart

This is my first post here, hopefully it makes sense.

I'm trying to write a FastAPI route that will receive a MIME file which is delivered with multipart/related. I am not interested in checking the data in any way, I literally want to receive the data/files and write it out to disk. Writing the file is simple and works with multipart/form-data, sadly this is not what I am receiving from the sender.

I don't have control over the sender and the data is delivered as multipart/related.

I have tried to curl in a MIME file to test the data which I will be receiving and have managed to simulate the same status code 422 issue I had with the real data.

The error message I am seeing and don't understand how to fix; `{"detail":[{"loc":["body","file"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}`

I have googled the error and seen response for the same issue, but nothing I have read has helped me solve the 422 issue.

This is a similar curl;
`curl --request POST -H "Transfer-Encoding: Chunked" -H "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=theboundary" -H "Content-Length: 6797" -H -F file=@./temp.mime http://127.0.0.1:8000/upf`

I have tried a few different fastAPI endpoints and can't get anything to work with multipart/related.

Here is an example of one of the endpoint routes which returns a 422;

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import uvicorn
import aiofiles

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/upf")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print("filename = ", file.filename) # getting filename
    destination_file_path = file.filename # location to store file
    async with aiofiles.open(destination_file_path, 'wb') as out_file:
        while content := await file.read(1024):  # async read file chunk
            await out_file.write(content)  # async write file chunk

    return {"Result": "OK"}
```

I also tried

```
@app.post("/save/")
async def receive_file(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...), ):
```

with a similar block of code.

It feels like I am missing something but can't understand what it is. Any help massively appreciated.

Comment: I am striving for the same multipart/related cable endpoint, I would suppose in the `create_upload_file` arguments you should either have the file and `data`/`json` or have a list of `files` as the `related` may give you muliple files at once.